# cocos2d-x export plist from images in windows free tool to use

Tags: cocos2d-x

as i learn to use cocos2d-x in the part on which i need to animate sprite images
all the tutorials shows how to use something that called plist file that maps the     coordinates of the images clips .
the problem is i didn't found any free tool in windows that export such file . 
can someone please point me where i can fins such tool ?

Comment: "Which technology to use" questions are off topic for the site. See the [FAQ] to learn what types of questions to ask here and what kind to not ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a project named [Sprite Sheet Packer](http://spritesheetpacker.codeplex.com/) which is designed to create sprite sheets, recently I've wrote a plist exporter and you can download it from [here](http://spritesheetpacker.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/patches). though you need to compile it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the replay , but what if i have already sprite sheet
that i need to mark its clips and convert it to plist file ?
i need some kind of GUI tool right ?

Comment: sadly I don't know any tool for that, personally I would break that spritesheet into several files (for example using paint) and then glow them together with SpriteSheetPacker :D I guess there are other tools out there too to help you break your initial file

Comment: yeah thanks for help i dont what to start cuting 40 images now

Comment: the txt that generated can be renamed to pilst ?

Comment: nope, plist files are basically xml format.

Comment: and to cut images, I'm using [paint.net](www.getpaint.net/)

Comment: also i dont understand basic thing here , the file that the app created dont look like .plist format ( that is full xml type )

Comment: @user3689 plist format is xml, it's just formatted in some special way. As I said I'm currently loading plist files exported by that application using `CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->addSpriteFramesWithFile("Menu.plist");` note that since file name is not written in plist file (it's optional) both plist file and the png file created should be placed in same folder and should have same name (with different extensions) (and remember iPhone is case sensitive)

Comment: you rename the txt file to pli‌​st file ?

Comment: nope, I'm using the plist exporter I've already mentioned. goto source page and look for plist exporter patch. you need to compile it though.

Comment: Hmm do i miss something but after downloading the plist patch and compiling i still cant see the exporter any where ? 
i mean in the GUI Sprite Sheet Packer.exe

Comment: after compiling that patch you should see plist between available types while choosing map file. but if anything went wrong I'm almost always available in [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) just ping me there and we'll figure out what's wrong,